# How to create trigger after alter table that makes copy of added column with suffix _vis to another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2019

Hello I feel really stuck because i don't code in SQL that often,

I have two tables one is **Subproject** and **SubprojectVisibilitySettings**

**Example columns in tables**

**Table Subproject** - **SubprojectId | SubprojectName | SubprojectType**

**Table SubprojectVisibilitySettings** - **UserName | SubprojectId_vis | SubprojectName_Vis | SubprojectType_Vis**

I need to make a trigger that checks if new column was added to **Subproject** table if yes then also add the column with the same name + suffix "**_Vis**" to table **SubprojectVisibilitySettings** table.

**Expected result**

Table **Subproject** - SubprojectId | SubprojectName | SubprojectType | **SubprojectDate**

Table **SubprojectVisibilitySettings** - UserName | SubprojectId_vis | SubprojectName_Vis | SubprojectType_Vis | **SuprojectDate_Vis**

If someone would help me to solve this I would be really thankful.

Comment: Are you *really* still using SQL Server 2008? That version ran *completely* out of support in 2019, that's *4 years* ago. It is *long* past time you got your finalised upgrade path implemented as using such an old and an insecure version is a significant security risk.

Comment: @ThomA sorry that was a mistake Im actually using SQL server 2019.

Comment: Gonna be difficult. You'd have to make a DDL trigger, and parse out the `EventData()` xml using XQuery. You'd need to then parse the SQL `ALTER` command from `EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText` and somehow work out what command to run on the other table. See also https://www.sqlshack.com/database-level-ddl-trigger-over-the-table/ Considering how rarely DDL commands are run, it's probably not worth it, you may as well just fix whatever is doing these commands to do the other table also.

Comment: What kind of workflow are you running that needs triggers to create columns? Why not just ... create columns in both tables when you do it

Comment: This sounds a lot like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @siggemannen my senior coworker wanted this from me so we don't need to add the columns on two tables separately :) Personaly I wouldn't care if I would do 2 alter tables instead of 1 but you know... Sometimes you do what you must do :)

Comment: Yeah, but it triplicates complexity, especially if you make a mistake. @Charlieface what he can do is to check so "something" happened to Subproject table, and then manually compare the columns between the two tables. I still think it's a bad idea, and i'm senior too :D

Comment: @siggemannen Well i guess we won't do any mistakes lol.

Answer (score 1):

I found one way to create trigger for my needs I don't know if its good solution but works for me. So if someone struggles like me just try this.

**Creating the trigger**

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [AddColumnTrigger]
ON DATABASE
FOR ALTER_TABLE
AS
BEGIN
    -- Check if the target table is Subproject
    IF EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(128)') = 'Subproject'
    BEGIN
        
        DECLARE @columnName NVARCHAR(128) -- the added column name

        SELECT TOP 1 @columnName = COLUMN_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Subproject'
            AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (
                SELECT REPLACE(name, '_Vis', '')
                FROM sys.columns
                WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('SubprojectVisibility')
            )
        ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION DESC

        -- Check if the column exists and is not present in SubprojectVisibility
        IF @columnName IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM sys.columns
            WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('SubprojectVisibility')
                AND name = @columnName + '_Vis'
        )
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
            SET @sql = N'
                ALTER TABLE SubprojectVisibility
                ADD ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName + '_Vis') + ' TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT (0);
            '
-- replace TINYINT with desired dataType and value
            EXEC sp_executesql @sql
        END
    END
END
GO
ENABLE TRIGGER [AddColumnTrigger] ON DATABASE
GO
```

Alter table **Subproject** adding new column

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Subproject
ADD NewExampleColumn int;
```

**The result**

```
Subproject 

SubprojectId | SubprojectName | NewExampleColumn

SubprojectVisibility

SubprojectId_vis | SubprojectName_Vis |  NewExampleColumn_Vis
```

Comment: what happens when someone adds a nvarchar(100) column

Comment: When i add nvarchar(100) its working, but when i add nvarchar(128) its added into Subproject but not into SubprojectVisibility

Comment: ok, but you always want tinyint as datatype?

Comment: Yes its just client settings to see columns. 0 hidden 1 shown 2 not allowed to hide/show

Comment: oh ok, then i guess it's "working" =)

Comment: There's a much better solution here https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/112459/220697 Yours does not take into account different column names, data types, nullability etc.